# How to check if users is owner of current post/topic in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'd like to let users to edit own post but I don't know how to check if user is post owner in thyemeleaf.

Is there any attribute to check if current user is owner?

Comment: please post some code where you want to compare the post owner and current user

Comment: @Avinash if I had i would ... but I don't know how to even start. I know only how to check if current user is "user" or "admin" by `sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')`

Comment: Since you're new, you need to first try a solution/code before posting a question. Anyway, you want the user to edit only if he has `ROLE_ADMIN`?

Comment: @Michael check the code you should find a post entity and this entity should have an attribute called author or something like that, then only thing you need to do is compare the author of your post with the current logged user. Paste the code as soon as you find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have not posted your code here but generally logged in user is maintained by session and you can match the post owner and current user like below.

```
${session.userId == postOwner}
```

The above will return true if the current user is post owner otherwise false and based upon this you can implement your logic.

Comment: I wasn't able to get userID, but I've done "workaround" 'th:if="${#authentication.name}==${topic.user.username} or ${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}"'